Irrationality measure of $\Gamma(1/3)$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$.
The numbers $\Gamma(1/3)$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$ are among the few rational values of the gamma function which are known to be irrational (and transcendental). They are also known not to be Liouville numbers, as stated by Waldschmidt (here in 2.3 and here on p.71) and proved by Philippon (here in Corollary 2, see also here, both in french). Does this give any (good) upper bounds on their respective irrationality measures?

A quick look at Wolfram's mathworld would suggest the upper bounds for more famous constants are very recent (all published in 2000's). If they're not Liouville numbers, finding lower bound $>2$ would be interesting on its own.

I'm not sure if you could call it a good upper bound, but according to Wikipedia, $\Gamma(1/4)$ has an irrationality measure upper bound of $10^{330}$. Additionally, based on Theorem 36 of the paper referenced by that article, as well as the paper it was deduced from, also by Philippon, it seems a similar bound could be found for $\Gamma(1/3)$ and other related constants (though it is hard for me to say for sure as I can't read French).

$10^{330}$ is such an unreasonably large constant to see on a list where everything else is less than $10$
